# How to programmatically check whether tool is installed on remote computer

Tags: java

How to programmatically check whether a certain tool is installed?
i want to copy files from A to B and i do that with sshpass and scp. So both of these tools have to be installed on the receiving end as well.
for the local computer i do it like this within Java:

```
builder = new ProcessBuilder("which", "sshpass");
```

or

```
process = Runtime
                    .getRuntime()
                    .exec("cmd /c  "where sshpass.exe\"");
```

to find installation directories for the tools.
What would be the best way to check on the remote computer from within a Java class on the local computer?
**Compared to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488118/how-to-programatically-check-if-a-software-utility-is-installed-on-ubuntu-using), i would like to execute the check for the remote computer.** The question does not have an answer yet.

Comment: Just try to connect? Almost definition of "remote", if you need "live" information about a remote system, you have to connect to it (or use some 3rd server where both you and remote connect to).

Answer (score -1):

The way you presented things makes it a bit obscure. Is it your tool or something you installed?

If it is your tool I would suggest adding what you need as functionality in it. You can add a "ping/pong" like function.

If it is not your tool consider checking how it works and what responses you get according to what you sent. Check if it uses specific ports, etc.